# How to have Zoom.us default to allowing remote participants to SHARE SCREEN

Tags: zoom.us

Zoom.us (Version 5.x)  limits screensharing to only the Host, by default.
You have to enable sharing for all participants *every session*.

Is there a way to change that default to allow all to screenshare every session?

Answer (score 0):

Under your profile on the Zoom portal, click on `Settings` on the left.

There will be an option called "Screen sharing" under the "In Meeting (Basic)" section as shown in this picture:

[image: Screen sharing settings option]

You can then toggle this setting to allow all participants to share their screen for the meetings where you are the host.

As per the [Zoom help center](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362153-Sharing-your-screen-content-or-second-camera):

> For Free/Basic accounts, screen sharing is set to **Only Host** by default.

Hence, this setting will need to be changed to allow all participants to share their screen by default.